# Given $g$ is differentiable at $x = a$, prove the following limit exists

Tags: limits

Given $g$ is differentiable at $x = a$, prove the following limit exists

- $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h)-g(a-6h)}{12h}$

After reading this similar post:

[if $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ then the limit exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839419/if-f-is-differentiable-at-x-0-then-the-limit-exists)

I tried applying similar logic but I'm stuck at this point because I don't know how to deal with $6h$ and $12h$.

- $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h)-g(a-6h)}{12h}$ = $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h) -g(a) + g(a) - g(a-6h)}{12h}$

I imagine you can set $f(x) = g(a+6h)$ but this is where I got up to. Any tips?

Edit: If $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+h) -g(a)}{h}$ = $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h) -g(a)}{12h}$ then I see how I can finish the question

So,

- $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{2}\frac{g(a+6h) -g(a) + g(a) - g(a-6h)}{6h}$ = $\frac{1}{2}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h) -g(a) + g(a) - g(a-6h)}{6h}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$$\lim_{h \to 0} (\frac{g(a+6h) -g(a)}{6h} + \frac{g(a) - g(a-6h)}{6h})$ = $\frac{1}{2}$$\lim_{h \to 0} (\frac{g(a+6h) -g(a)}{6h} + \frac{g(a+6h^*) - g(a)}{6h^*})$
  = $\frac{1}{2}$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h) -g(a)}{6h}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h^*) -g(a)}{6h^*}$

And we know that since $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+h) -g(a)}{h}$ exists and is equal to $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h) -g(a)}{6h}$ we have

- $\frac{1}{2}$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h) -g(a)}{6h}$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h^*) -g(a)}{6h^*}$ that also exist

Comment: In you last line it should be $6h$ on the denominator, so you'll get a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ to take care of. Keep going, you've got the right idea.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks for that, I think I got it in the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a hint : use a substitution $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h)-g(a-6h)}{12h}
$ for example use $6h =u \to h=\frac {1}{6}u$  so $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(a+6h)-g(a-6h)}{12h}=\\\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{g(a+u)-g(a-u)}{2u}\\\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{g(a+u)-g(a)+g(a)-g(a-u)}{2u}
$$Hope it helps you

Comment: I just edited in the comment's hint, not sure if the last line is correct

Comment: @TingoHugo: your last line edit is not true.

Comment: Yea I thought so, thanks

Answer (score 0):

By definition, using little-o notation, we have

- $g(a+6h)=g(a)+g'(a)\cdot 6h + o(h)$
- $g(a-6h)=g(a)+g'(a)\cdot (-6h) + o(h)$

and then

$$\frac{g(a+6h)-g(a-6h)}{12h}=g'(a)+o(1)\to g'(a)$$

Refer also to:

- [Differentiability Using Little Oh Notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4061952/505767)

Comment: Where did the $o(h)$ come from? Why is it not just $g(a) + g'(a)6h$?

Comment: @TingoHugo It is an equivalent definition of differentiability. Refer also to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4061952/505767

Comment: @TingoHugo $o(h)$ is a remainder term it is zero if the function is locally a line otherwise we have also this term.

Comment: Oh cool, I've never come across that but thats interesting

Comment: This is an important concept indeed and very useful as a first (order) taste for the more general Taylor expansion.